# Confluent/ Kafka support for the upcoming Java 17 LTS

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Has Confluent shared any plans for supporting the [upcoming Java 17 LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) release? I am mostly interested in the java client libraries. The [official documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#clients) does not mention any version after Java 11 (the current latest LTS release).

Apache Kafka itself seems to be supporting [Java 17](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/11296). Same for [Confluent Schema Registry](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/2032). But in the official Confluent docs I see [no Java 17 reference](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#java).

UPDATE: Kafka Streams API seems to be working fine with Java 17, based on extensive usage, for more than 2 months for my current client.

UPDATE: Java 17 is the [recommended version](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#java) in this version of Confluent Platform

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question should use proper communication channels with Confluent like their support email, their own support forum, or join their community slack. For Apache Kafka itself, join the developer mailing lists or JIRA. Confluent won't support it until it's available in Apache anyway